# rails 6.1: cannot load such file -- prawn-table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, prawn

I am using the prawn gem to create pdf's. So, to create tables requires using the separate prawn-table gem.

For some reason, I am unable to require the prawn table gem and have no clues as to why.

The result is:

**require': cannot load such file -- prawn-table (LoadError)**

For some reason, the prawn-table gem cannot be loaded. **Why not?**

The gems exist in the gem env path (see below):

```
bundle info prawn
  * prawn (2.4.0)
        Summary: A fast and nimble PDF generator for Ruby
        Homepage: http://prawnpdf.org
        Path: /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/prawn-2.4.0

bundle info prawn-table
  * prawn-table (0.2.2)
        Summary: Provides tables for PrawnPDF
        Homepage: https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-table
        Path: /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/prawn-table-0.2.2
```

I call the prawn generator like so...

```
require 'prawn'
require 'prawn/measurement_extensions'
require 'prawn-table'

def generate_pdf(invoice, mode)
 Prawn::Document.generate(invoice.file, margin_top: 0, page_size: 'A4',
                                           info:
  {...
```

which results in:

```
invoicer generate --mode development
Traceback (most recent call last):
        20: from ./bin/invoicer:4:in `<main>'
        19: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        18: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
        17: from /home/cb/work/invoicer/lib/invoicer.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        16: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        15: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        14: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        13: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:148:in `require'
        12: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:148:in `require'
        11: from /home/cb/work/invoicer/lib/invoicer/invoice_process.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
         9: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
         8: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
         7: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:148:in `require'
         6: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:148:in `require'
         5: from /home/cb/work/invoicer/lib/invoicer/generate_pdf.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
         3: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
         2: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
         1: from /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:148:in `require'
/home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:148:in `require': cannot load such file -- prawn-table (LoadError)
```

My gem env looks like this:

> RubyGems Environment:
>
> - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.14
> - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.6 (2020-03-31 patchlevel 146) [x86_64-linux]
> - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6
> - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
> - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby
> - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
> - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/bin
> - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/cb/.gem/specs
> - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/etc
> - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>
>   - ruby
>   - x86_64-linux
> - GEM PATHS:
>
>   - /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6
>   - /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
> - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>
>   - :update_sources => true
>   - :verbose => true
>   - :backtrace => false
>   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
> - REMOTE SOURCES:
>
>   - https://rubygems.org/
> - SHELL PATH:
>
>   - /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/bin
>   - /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin
>   - /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin
>   - /usr/local/sbin
>   - /usr/local/bin
>   - /usr/sbin
>   - /usr/bin
>   - /sbin
>   - /bin
>   - /usr/games
>   - /usr/local/games
>   - /snap/bin
>   - .
>   - bin

```
rails 6.1 load path
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.3)
irb(main):001:0> $:
[
    [ 0] "/home/cb/work/invoicer/lib",
    [ 1] "/home/cb/work/invoicer/vendor",
    [ 2] "/home/cb/work/invoicer/app/helpers",
    [ 3] "/home/cb/work/invoicer/app/mailers",
    [ 4] "/home/cb/work/invoicer/app/models",
    [ 5] "/home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionview-6.1.3/lib",
    [ 6] "/home/cb/work/invoicer",
    [ 7] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/whenever-1.0.0/lib",
    [ 8] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/web-console-4.1.0/lib",
    [ 9] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/lib",
    [10] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0-static/sqlite3-1.4.2",
    [11] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/rails-6.1.3/lib",
    [12] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib",
    [13] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/sprockets-4.0.2/lib",
    [14] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/railties-6.1.3/lib",
    [15] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib",
    [16] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.1/lib",
    [17] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/prawn-table-0.2.2/lib",
    [18] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/prawn-2.4.0/lib",
    [19] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/ttfunk-1.7.0/lib",
    [20] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/pdf-core-0.9.0/lib",
    [21] "/home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/method_source-1.0.0/lib",
    .
    .
    .
    [93] "/home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0",
    [94] "/home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-linux"
]
```

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-table/issues/37) helps.

Comment: Unfortunately no. That article would seem to suggest that bundler is not handling the dependencies correctly, however, trying the various combinations of forcing the dependencies makes no difference

Answer (score 3):

IMO instead of

```
require "prawn-table"
```

you should use

```
require "prawn/table"
```

Comment: Thanks. You are correct of course, but even that wouldn't work. I did solve the puzzle. I had another project ostensibly doing the same thing with prawn but for which there are no requires, so I assume that zeitwerk did its thing. Unfortunately not in this case. So, I removed the prawn gems from all projects and re-bundled and used `require 'prawn/table'` and sure enough it now worked. So it would appear as though it was a bundler issue in some way after all across the 2 projects.